# Float (double) value gets corrupted in a string with other values

Tags: floating-point, printf, atmega, avr-gcc

I am working with an ATMEGA328PB AVR microcontroller and keep running into a problem when sending out certain floating point numbers via the UART.

I have enabled floating point with my compiler (avr-gcc) and it mostly works.

For instance, this code:

```
floatVal = ((double)tempResult / (double)oversample) * 0.000457777;
char outbuffer[255];
sprintf(outbuffer, "%f\n", floatVal);
usart1TXString(outbuffer);
```

Provides the correct output on the UART:

```
3.866311
```

I also want to print out a 32bit int.  This also works:

```
char outbuffer[255];
sprintf(outbuffer, "%ld\n", transform(combVal));
usart1TXString(outbuffer);
```

And provides the correct output on the UART:

```
117864
```

(both these outputs are exactly what I expect them to be)

The problem occurs when I try to combine these two pieces of code into a single (or even successive) transmission:

```
floatVal = ((double)tempResult / (double)oversample) * 0.000457777;
char outbuffer[255];
sprintf(outbuffer, "%f,%ld\n", floatVal, transform(combVal));
usart1TXString(outbuffer);
```

produces this output:

```
584991570000.000000,117864
```

The large number does not change, unless my floatVal is a much different value.

I tried breaking it up into two different transmissions with no luck:

```
floatVal = ((double)tempResult / (double)oversample) * 0.000457777;
char outbuffer[255];
sprintf(outbuffer, "%f\n", floatVal);
usart1TXString(outbuffer);
char outbuffertwo[255];
sprintf(outbuffertwo, ",%ld\n", transform(combVal));
usart1TXString(outbuffertwo);
```

Produces the same erroneous result.

```
584991570000.000000,117419
```

I also tried using dtostrf() instead of sprintf():

```
floatVal = ((double)tempResult / (double)oversample) * 0.000457777;
char outbuffer[255];
dtostrf(floatVal, 6, 4, outbuffer);
usart1TXString(outbuffer);
```

Works.  But as soon as I try to add the other value, it breaks again:

```
floatVal = ((double)tempResult / (double)oversample) * 0.000457777;
char outbuffer[255];
dtostrf(floatVal, 6, 4, outbuffer);
usart1TXString(outbuffer);
char outbuffertwo[255];
sprintf(outbuffertwo, ",%ld\n", transform(combVal));
usart1TXString(outbuffertwo);
```

Back to the same broken values coming out the UART.

I tried increasing the size of the buffer (even though it should already be more than large enough).

I don't think it matters but just in case:

'tempResult' is an unsigned 64 bit int that is an accumulation of 16 bit values received from an ADC.

'oversample' is a 16 bit int that is the amount of oversampling specified.  Currently 50.

'floatVal' is a double.

'combVal' is a 32 bit int that contains a 24 bit ADC value in two's compliment.

transform() is a function to deal with the two's compliment number and looks like this:

```
int32_t transform(int32_t value)
    {
        if (value > MAX_VALUE)
        {
            value -= MODULO;
        }
        return value;
    }
```

What is it about the %ld that is corrupting the %f?

EDIT:  Even if I replace the `transform(combVal)` with just a variable containing the correct number, it still corrupts the other value.

Comment: What does  code use `"%ld"` with `int32_t transform()` instead of `"%" PRId32`?

Comment: Likely culprits: compiler only handles `float` 2) UB somewhere else - just shows up here. 3) Missing declarations 4) compiler bug.  A [mcve] would improve this post.

Comment: Thank you @chux-ReinstateMonica.  It was indeed UB.  See my answer below if you are curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, and it was in one of those things I said I don't think matters.  Specifically this:

`'tempResult' is an unsigned 64 bit int that is an accumulation of 16 bit values received from an ADC.`

From the avr-libc FAQ:

```
float and double are 32 bits (this is the only supported floating point format)
```

I narrowed the problem down to this line:

```
floatVal = ((double)tempResult / (double)oversample) * 0.000457777;
```

since if I replaced it with this:

```
floatVal = 3.123456
```

everything works as expected.

Changing `uint64_t tempResult;` to `uint32_t tempResult;` fixes everything.  I just need to not get too carried away with oversampling and everything will be fine.

Long story short:  Abusing floating point on an 8bit AVR was causing UB, which was doing what UB likes to do (work sometimes and causes a lot of confusion others).